# Angular4 Widgets Communication in a non angular web application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, widget

I want to create an angular4 app which is comprised of independent widgets (angular4 modules) that communicate with each other.

As a simple example, `ShelfWidget` has `ItemComponent`s and they can be added to `BucketWidget` by a button click on the page. Similarly, a remove button should also be there to place an `ItemComponent` from the `BucketWidget` to `ShelfWidget`.

I can easily implement this in an angular app. **So I request you not to label this question as a duplicate of another angular component communication question.**

I want to get an AOT build of this app and import the 4 script files and 1 css files generated by the AOT build inside a non-angular website, for example, a **wamp server** index page. Then, I want to use those two widgets inside this `index.html` page as follows.

```
<shelf-widget></shelf-widget>
<bucket-widget></bucket-widget>

<button (click)="takeItem()">Put into bucket</button>
<button (click)="removeItem()">Remove from bucket</button>
```

It would be really helpful if I could get an answer on how to use Angular4 modules as standalone html tags within a non angular environment with an example codes and procedures. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is quite an interesting question would be cool if you post an use case. Anyway some googling arround I found this, eventually it already helps you a little bit: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2017/04/10/using-angular-2-components-in-a-non-angular-app/

Comment: Yes sir. I already watched it. But I was unable to implement. I think because of angular2 syntax in the example. Also, I am unable to get an error free AOT build also. thanks @Doomenik